# drizzle not updating events properly - duplicate events

Tags: events, drizzle

I'm facing a peculiar problem while rendering event values in a component using drizzle. When a new event is created and is updated in the events array of drizzle (drizzleState.contracts.MyContract.events), it initially shows loads of duplicate events in the array like below:

```
0: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0xf45de779dc613beb7dbf548fb1a811711ec6225c30376aa14cb8989459cda146", blockHash: "0xbba89434b400d1530289369e4fec52e423ac8699f45bf19ae8004755fcdea278", blockNumber: 39, …}
1: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x1cd02901ca748218a0037a07294d30dc8e00a05b1e9aebeed013ffff468c1b82", blockHash: "0x08201e408f4080c1ef35ce86ace61130faf0fe821b89187969c7ae7e40b57e8a", blockNumber: 37, …}
2: {logIndex: 1, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x1cd02901ca748218a0037a07294d30dc8e00a05b1e9aebeed013ffff468c1b82", blockHash: "0x08201e408f4080c1ef35ce86ace61130faf0fe821b89187969c7ae7e40b57e8a", blockNumber: 37, …}
3: {logIndex: 2, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x1cd02901ca748218a0037a07294d30dc8e00a05b1e9aebeed013ffff468c1b82", blockHash: "0x08201e408f4080c1ef35ce86ace61130faf0fe821b89187969c7ae7e40b57e8a", blockNumber: 37, …}
4: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
5: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
6: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
7: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
8: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
9: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
10: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
11: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
12: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
length: 13
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The above code block is the brwser console log of the events array which shows duplicate items starting from index number 5 to 12. On refreshing the page (pressing F5), the duplicate events dissappear and the correct values show up:

```
 0: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0xf45de779dc613beb7dbf548fb1a811711ec6225c30376aa14cb8989459cda146", blockHash: "0xbba89434b400d1530289369e4fec52e423ac8699f45bf19ae8004755fcdea278", blockNumber: 39, …}
1: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x0bfb0418d11eb77a8874f5f294fe83964aecdbe181f5b05c5335f625ead59d9c", blockHash: "0xf03598bdfd7de5c1e99c5ce3f429c989b515ccc5043de919956d5ef7c7ecbc98", blockNumber: 40, …}
2: {logIndex: 0, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x1cd02901ca748218a0037a07294d30dc8e00a05b1e9aebeed013ffff468c1b82", blockHash: "0x08201e408f4080c1ef35ce86ace61130faf0fe821b89187969c7ae7e40b57e8a", blockNumber: 37, …}
3: {logIndex: 1, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x1cd02901ca748218a0037a07294d30dc8e00a05b1e9aebeed013ffff468c1b82", blockHash: "0x08201e408f4080c1ef35ce86ace61130faf0fe821b89187969c7ae7e40b57e8a", blockNumber: 37, …}
4: {logIndex: 2, transactionIndex: 0, transactionHash: "0x1cd02901ca748218a0037a07294d30dc8e00a05b1e9aebeed013ffff468c1b82", blockHash: "0x08201e408f4080c1ef35ce86ace61130faf0fe821b89187969c7ae7e40b57e8a", blockNumber: 37, …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This is causing the render to show duplicate values which is mitigated only when an extra refresh button is pressed in the browser. Is this a bug or am i missing something? Thanks.